# Error with conekta module

Tags: payment-methods

I have added the plugin of conekta, but when you try to enter "Payment Methods" says that there is an error with the 500 error page. In the logs said this:

Error   187.189.50.7    500 GET /index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/payment/key/9730b5c8b995abc9ded1683acac9ea19/ HTTP/1.0

```
Warning 187.189.50.7        mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/app/code/community/Conekta/Webhook/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Url.php on line 36, referer: http://domain.com/index.php/admin/system_config/index/key/70711712bcc676261f6ea32715cafe34/
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: can you post it in English? I ddin't understand your language.

Comment: @VenuJoginpally it is the year 2017, there is something called Google that leads you to technology that allows you to translate.

Comment: @SR_Magento ohhh is it?? anyways,thanks for translating.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem using "empty" on a function return:

```
if (!empty(Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/webhook/privatekey'))) {
```

There are two options to solve this:
1.- Assign the function return to a variable: "empty($someVar)".
2.- Update your PHP version. It seems to work on 5.6.27.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532693/weird-php-error-cant-use-function-return-value-in-write-context

I'm sure that if you contact Conekta's team via their customer support or  Magento Connect they will fix the bug ASAP.

Comment: Version 0.8.2 of the plugin should have this fixed!
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/conekta-payment-method-extension.html